# Scala Apache Commons embed image into email

Tags: html, scala, embed, html-email, apache-commons

I recently started my first job after uni, and I am now working on a pretty big project. I have been tasked with embedding the company's logo into the emails, as for some email clients (mainly Outlook), images are automatically blocked.

Emails are configured with Apache Commons `HtmlEmail`, with templates configured in an `.xml` file. I was playing around and managed to embed an email the following way:

```
String cid = email.embed(url, "logo");
  
  // set the html message
  email.setHtmlMsg("<html><img src=\"cid:"+cid+"\"></html>");
```

But of course the email template wasn't configured for this. So I simply implemented a `.replace()` to replace the existing `src` with the new `cid` one. I printed the HTML message, and all looked good, but when the email comes through, no image is displayed, and I don't even have the option to show images.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution.

CID embedding and straight Base64 encoding (which CID uses) are not fully supported across email clients, most notably Gmail and Outlook https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/

There is essentially no way around it (unless you want to recreate it using tables, background colours, and HTML text).

If you really wanted to do it, mainly for Outlook's sake, you can use Outlook-only code. But note the length of your email, and the fact that Gmail and other email providers may cut the length of your email (at about 101kb), forcing users to click 'see full email' and load the email from the start again to see the full email (not a good experience at all).

```
<!--[if mso]>-->
  <!-- Insert embedded image code here -->
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]>-->
  <!-- Insert normal <img src> code here -->
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This is what I thought, my manager thinks there is a way, but I have found no definitive way, thanks for the help. I will take a look at that link.

Comment: Updated if you must go down this route @LondonMassive